# Spring Security - Remember Me custom service onLoginSuccess not called using oauth2

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement a remember me functionality, with a jHipster generated webapp. I'm updating an old project login page, which will have a remember me checkbox.

The problem I'm having is that the RememberMeServices I'm implementing doesn't work. To be precise, the method onLoginSuccess is not called, and the initialization of the persistent token does not happen.

Nevertheless the method logout of CustomPersistentRememberMeServices is called.

I have a custom remember me service defined like this:

```
@Service("rememberMeServices")
public class CustomPersistentRememberMeServices extends
 AbstractRememberMeServices {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.class);

// Token is valid for one month
private static final int TOKEN_VALIDITY_DAYS = 31;

private static final int TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * TOKEN_VALIDITY_DAYS;

private static final int DEFAULT_SERIES_LENGTH = 16;

private static final int DEFAULT_TOKEN_LENGTH = 16;

private SecureRandom random;

@Inject
private PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;

@Inject
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Inject
public CustomPersistentRememberMeServices(Environment env, org.springframework.security.core.userdetails
    .UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {

    super(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"), userDetailsService);
    random = new SecureRandom();
}

@Override
@Transactional
protected UserDetails processAutoLoginCookie(String[] cookieTokens, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) {

    PersistentToken token = getPersistentToken(cookieTokens);
    String login = token.getUser().getLogin();

    // Token also matches, so login is valid. Update the token value, keeping the *same* series number.
    log.debug("Refreshing persistent login token for user '{}', series '{}'", login, token.getSeries());
    token.setTokenDate(LocalDate.now());
    token.setTokenValue(generateTokenData());
    token.setIpAddress(request.getRemoteAddr());
    token.setUserAgent(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
    try {
        persistentTokenRepository.saveAndFlush(token);
        addCookie(token, request, response);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        log.error("Failed to update token: ", e);
        throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException("Autologin failed due to data access problem", e);
    }
    return getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(login);
}

@Override
protected void onLoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication
    successfulAuthentication) {

    String login = successfulAuthentication.getName();

    log.debug("Creating new persistent login for user {}", login);
    PersistentToken token = userRepository.findOneByLogin(login).map(u -> {
        PersistentToken t = new PersistentToken();
        t.setSeries(generateSeriesData());
        t.setUser(u);
        t.setTokenValue(generateTokenData());
        t.setTokenDate(LocalDate.now());
        t.setIpAddress(request.getRemoteAddr());
        t.setUserAgent(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
        return t;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + login + " was not found in the database"));
    try {
        persistentTokenRepository.saveAndFlush(token);
        addCookie(token, request, response);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        log.error("Failed to save persistent token ", e);
    }
}

/**
 * When logout occurs, only invalidate the current token, and not all user sessions.
 * <p/>
 * The standard Spring Security implementations are too basic: they invalidate all tokens for the
 * current user, so when he logs out from one browser, all his other sessions are destroyed.
 */
@Override
@Transactional
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
    String rememberMeCookie = extractRememberMeCookie(request);
    if (rememberMeCookie != null && rememberMeCookie.length() != 0) {
        try {
            String[] cookieTokens = decodeCookie(rememberMeCookie);
            PersistentToken token = getPersistentToken(cookieTokens);
            persistentTokenRepository.delete(token);
        } catch (InvalidCookieException ice) {
            log.info("Invalid cookie, no persistent token could be deleted");
        } catch (RememberMeAuthenticationException rmae) {
            log.debug("No persistent token found, so no token could be deleted");
        }
    }
    super.logout(request, response, authentication);
}

/**
 * Validate the token and return it.
 */
private PersistentToken getPersistentToken(String[] cookieTokens) {
    if (cookieTokens.length != 2) {
        throw new InvalidCookieException("Cookie token did not contain " + 2 +
            " tokens, but contained '" + Arrays.asList(cookieTokens) + "'");
    }
    String presentedSeries = cookieTokens[0];
    String presentedToken = cookieTokens[1];
    PersistentToken token = persistentTokenRepository.findOne(presentedSeries);

    if (token == null) {
        // No series match, so we can't authenticate using this cookie
        throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException("No persistent token found for series id: " + presentedSeries);
    }

    // We have a match for this user/series combination
    log.info("presentedToken={} / tokenValue={}", presentedToken, token.getTokenValue());
    if (!presentedToken.equals(token.getTokenValue())) {
        // Token doesn't match series value. Delete this session and throw an exception.
        persistentTokenRepository.delete(token);
        throw new CookieTheftException("Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous " +
            "cookie theft attack.");
    }

    if (token.getTokenDate().plusDays(TOKEN_VALIDITY_DAYS).isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
        persistentTokenRepository.delete(token);
        throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException("Remember-me login has expired");
    }
    return token;
}

private String generateSeriesData() {
    byte[] newSeries = new byte[DEFAULT_SERIES_LENGTH];
    random.nextBytes(newSeries);
    return new String(Base64.encode(newSeries));
}

private String generateTokenData() {
    byte[] newToken = new byte[DEFAULT_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    random.nextBytes(newToken);
    return new String(Base64.encode(newToken));
}

private void addCookie(PersistentToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    setCookie(
        new String[]{token.getSeries(), token.getTokenValue()},
        TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, request, response);
}
```

And a security configuration class defined this way:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Inject
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "CSRF-TOKEN")
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/dump/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/shutdown/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/beans/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/configprops/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/env/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/liquibase/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getClientid())
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
                .secret(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getSecret())
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getTokenValidityInSeconds());
    }
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that the login method is not called? Did you put a breakpoint in there and debug the service, or are you relying on side-effects that you expect to happen if it were invoked?

Comment: I've set a breakpoint inside of onLoginSuccess and didn't stop. Reviewed the database for changes, expecting a new token, nothing happened.

Comment: Why the onLoginSuccess is not annotated with @Transactional?

Comment: I didn't see onLoginSuccess didn't have Transactional annotation, and I understand is required to persist changes to database. but adding Transactional does not change anything due onLoginSuccess is not called in absolute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spring security oauth, remember me service does not work due RememberMeAuthenticationFilter not being associated to login url (/oauth/token), even after using rememberMe configurer.

To be able to have a remember me functionality, is necessary to use refresh token to keep updating access tokens, and then be remembered.

You can read this two articles to have an idea of how to do it.
http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-remember-me